# Appending Complex HTML to div with javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom, innerhtml

i’m trying to create a javascript function which will append complex html to a div that is already in place (“complex” meaning more than a single element like

or  etc..). i can’t place the whole div inside the () of .innerHTML(“div”) without it registering as an error because of all the symbols that cause JS to stop reading the content as a string. any recommendations? is there a way for me to create the element in my HTML file and hide it until it is triggered by a function in the javascript? thank you! (html and js below)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href= "style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
   <div class = "row r1">
        <div class = "col-md-3"></div>
        <div class = "col-md-6">
        <h1>Your Password Generator</h1>
        </div>
        <div class = "col-md-3"></div>
    </div>

    <br><br><br>

    <div class = "row r2">
        <div class = "col-md-3"></div>
        <div class = "col-md-6 hello">
            <p>Hello, friend. Welcome to your new password generator. <br> Click "continue" to customize your password.</p>
        </div>
        <div class = "col-md-3"></div>
    </div>

    <br> <br>

    <div class = "row r3">
        <div class = "col-md-3"></div>
        <div class = "col-md-6">
            <div class = "cntrContent"></div>
        </div>
        <div class = "col-md-3"></div>
    </div>

    <div class = "characterSelect">
        </div><div class = "text-center">
       <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
              Special Characters
            </label> <br> 
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
              Numbers
            </label> <br> 
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
              Letters
            </label> 
    </div>


    <br> <br> 

    <div class = "row r4">
        <div class = "col-md-3"></div>
        <div class = "col-md-6">
            <div class= "text-center">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light button">Continue</button>
            </div>
        </div>   
        <div class = "col-md-3"></div>
    </div>

      <!-- initial display: "Hello, friend. Welcome to your new password generator. Click "continue" to customize your password
    then: new display, the question: "which kinds of characters would you like to include in your password?" followed by 
    list with checkboxes for "special character" "numbers" and "letters". this is followed by a "generate my password" button.
    their selections will run through conditionals with event listeners. the next page will display the password under header "your password"
    then a button below, "copy password to clipboard" and another button that says "i want another password" which brings
    user back to customization options.-->




        <script src="./script.js"></script>
```

```
JS:

var promptMsg = document.querySelector(".hello");
var cntrContent = document.querySelector(".cntrContent");
var button = document.querySelector(".button");
var characterSelect = document.querySelector(".characterSelect")




$(".button").on("click", function() {
    $(promptMsg).text("What kinds of characters would you like to include in your password?");
   $(characterSelect).innerHTML("THIS IS WHERE I AM TRYING TO APPEND THE DIV CLASSNAME 'characterSelect'")


})
```

Comment: here is where i am trying to append the div:

$(".button").on("click", function() {
    $(promptMsg).text("What kinds of characters would you like to include in your password?");
    $(cntrContent).innerHTML("MULTIFACETED DIV HERE");

is there a more straighforward way of going about this?

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: You will not get a meaningful answer without posting some of your code and what you have tried.

Comment: here's the html: <div class = "characterSelect">
        </div><div class = "text-center">
       <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
              Special Characters
            </label>

Comment: @user72503948573038 Update your original post with code (formatted). Also what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i have tried copy and pasting this div directly after the innerHTML method i.e. 
$(.characterSelect).innerHTML(<div class = "characterSelect">
        </div><div class = "text-center">
       <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
              Special Characters
            </label> )

Comment: @WhatisSober just updated original post, let me know if you have any ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing jquery methods with JS methods.

---

In your case, I recommend using [template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template)

```
<template id="myTemplate">
  htmlto append
</template>
```

and then you can use `append`.

With jquery:

```
var template = $("#myTemplate").html();
$(characterSelect).append(template);
```

With plain javascript:

```
var template = document.getElementById("myTemplate").content;
characterSelect.appendChild(template);
```

Here is a jsbin: https://jsbin.com/qucaxanohe/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to insert your HTML code inside the target div from the beginning, but hidden (using CSS's `display:none` or jQuery's `hide()`).

Then, in your function call, use jQuery's `show()` to show the hidden HTML whenever you want, like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#to_hide").hide();
});

//simulating some waiting before function call
//JUST FOR ILLUSTRATION PURPOSES, not needed in actual code
setTimeout(function() {
  callback();
}, 3000);


//your function that will show the div and do whatever you want to do here
function callback() {
  //whatever you want to do here
  $(".to_hide").show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="to_hide">
    <p>Some content</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems unnecessarily complicated to just show/hide an element. Why not just use toggle().

Comment: It will be exactly the same. Either use one show() and one hide(), or two toggle(), or CSS.

Comment: To clarify, the setTimeout is just to simulate some time elapsed, before the function calls, so that the difference can show in this snippet. There is no need for it in the actual code.

Comment: thank you all so much this fixed my problem completely!

Comment: @user72503948573038 Glad this helps! If this answered your question, please consider upvoting/marking as answer. Have a good day!